# Find a solution to $x''+x=g(t)$, $x(t_0)=x_0$, $x'(t_0)=x_0'$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find a solution to $x''+x=g(t)$, $x(t_0)=x_0$, $x'(t_0)=x_0'$, where $g$ is a continuous function in $\mathbb{R}$.

Somebody can give me a hint?

Comment: Or Laplace transforms

Comment: Or Fourier transforms